# Counting of comparison symbols in text file

Tags: python, file, python-3.x, counter

I am having trouble with one of my assignments.

I supposed to write a code were it takes a text file and calculates comparison symbols in it.

The problem is that it wont print '==', '>=' or '<='

My code:

```
from collections import Counter

chars = ['==', '>=', '<=', '<', '>']
file = open(input('specify a file'))
character_distr = Counter()

for line in file:
    character_distr += Counter(line.lower())

print('Distribution of characters: ')
for char, count in sorted(character_distr.items()):
    if char in chars:
    print('{}  :  {}'.format(char, count))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
c1 = Counter('hello there')
```

Then try this:

```
c2 = Counter('hello there'.split())
```

Note the difference?  When a `Counter` is fed a string, it counts *characters*.  You need to `split` your string into a `list` if you want it to count tokens other than individual characters.

So if there are conveniently spaces in between your operators, add `.split()` to `line.lower()` and there you go.  If there's not (which is, of course, legal), you'll need to get a bit more sophisticated with a lexer or (more likely) regex.

```
import re
expression = 'if x>4: do_thing(); elif x==12: other_thing = x'

len(re.findall(r'==|>=|<=|<|>',expression))
Out[12]: 2
```